# How to give a python program two optional command-line integer arguments?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse, optional-arguments

I am helping a friend with some Python code. I am making a menu, and I would like to make the dimensions customizable. I have been playing with argparse, and I have had no luck. My idea is to have `menu.py`
default to 80*24, and have `menu.py 112 84` set to 112*84. I have my current code here:

```
import argparse
args = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='The menu')
width = length = 0
args.add_argument('--width', const=80, default=80, type=int,
                  help='The width of the menu.', nargs='?', required=False)
args.add_argument('--length', const=24, default-24, type=int,
                  help='The length of the menu.', nargs='?', required=False)
inpu = args.parse_args()
width = inpu.width
length = inpu.length
print(width)
print(length)
```

How can I do this with `argparse`?

Comment: _"The code indentation on StackOverflow was not working"_ - for future reference, here's StackOverflow's markdown reference: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie The preview was not showing formatting the way I thought it should. And the indentation was not formatting in the preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With (cleaned up a bit):

```
args.add_argument('-w','--width', const=84, default=80, type=int,
              help='The width of the menu.', nargs='?')
args.add_argument('-l','--length', const=28, default=24, type=int,
              help='The length of the menu.', nargs='?')
```

I expect

```
menu.py  => namespace(length=24, width=80)
menu.py -w -l -w => namespace(length=28, width=84)
menu.py -w 23 -l 32 => namespace(length=32, width=23)
```

If I change the arguments to

```
args.add_argument('width', default=80, type=int,
              help='The width of the menu.', nargs='?')
args.add_argument('length', default=24, type=int,
              help='The length of the menu.', nargs='?')
```

I'd expect

```
menu.py => namespace(length=24, width=80)
menu.py 32 => namespace(length=24, width=32)
menu.py 32 33 => namespace(length=33, width=32)
```

You could also use one argument with `nargs='*'`, and get a list of integers, `namespace=[32, 34]` that you could then split between `length` and `width`.